# setValue of row function need to modify from previous answer given

Tags: google-apps-script

Posting new question based on a previous question [set value of row for previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73380285/set-value-of-row-for-previous-month)
A function was written to setValue of rows if date is from previous month.

```
function hideRows() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("IAD(Tampa)");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dtv0 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() - 1,1).valueOf();
  const dtv1 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),1,0).valueOf();
  let rows = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[0]);
    let dv = d.valueOf();
    if(dv >= dtv0 && dv < dtv1) {
      rows.push(i+1);
      sh.getRange(i + 1,1).setValue(null);
    }
  })
}
```

If I wanted this formula to only setValue to dates 2 months and older I know that I can change const dtv0 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() - 2,1).valueOf(); but thats grabs everything except current month. How can I have it leave last months values? Example: dates are as follows 7/9/22 7/26/22 8/20/22 and today's date is 9/7/22 I want to leave 8/20/22 alone. I am not clear how to do this with the current function.

Solution is as follows: `function hideRows() { const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); const sh = ss.getSheetByName("IAD(Tampa)"); const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); const dtv0 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() - 1,1,new Date().getDate()).valueOf(); let rows = []; vs.forEach((r,i) => { let d = new Date(r[0]); let dv = d.valueOf(); if(dv < dtv0) { rows.push(i+1); sh.getRange(i + 1,1).setValue(null); } }) }`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function hideRows() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Archived Videos");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dtv0 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() - 1,1).valueOf();
  let rows = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[0]);
    let dv = d.valueOf();
    if(dv < dtv0) {
      rows.push(i+1);
      sh.getRange(i + 1,1).setValue(null);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Date(...).getDate is not a function
Line 5

Comment: That's 2 months and older

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1befqsGQvbPfn0XTGrygLOGcrUIMrICUagJVH0S-2rDw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula is working just fine now. I made an error on my part. Thanks for all the assistance

Comment: I added this to my live sheet and it wipes out dates for August... in my sample sheet it works just fine...After performing a test it deletes August dates if before today the 7th.

Comment: Your sheet name does not seem to appear to exist in that spreadsheet

Comment: Okay I see it's IAD(Tampa)

Comment: Apparently you want to start deleting everything one month and older

Comment: The data I am keeping record of is for all of the current month and all of the previous month. Everything else will be purged

Comment: @MiMi Is this not very clear?

Comment: Your code said that the sheet name was Archived Videos but evidently it was actually IAD(TAMPA) on the spreadsheet you shared with us

Comment: it will be IAD(Tampa), I will be copying this code for other sheets.

Comment: Solution is as follows:

function hideRows() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("IAD(Tampa)");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dtv0 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() - 1,1,new Date().getDate()).valueOf();
  let rows = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[0]);
    let dv = d.valueOf();
    if(dv < dtv0) {
      rows.push(i+1);
      sh.getRange(i + 1,1).setValue(null);
    }
  })
}

Comment: Actually there is an error in the code you posted in the  last comment

Comment: I originally meant to have the date be on the start of the current meant it to be `const dtv0 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() - 1,1).valueOf();` but I accidentally put `const dtv0 = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() - 1,1,new Date().getDate()).valueOf();` which may cause an  error on days of the month that are greater than 23.  I think what I have now in the posted answer is what you want.

Comment: My code worked for me somehow but you answer is what I'll use. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: In some sheets I want to setValue(null) but what if I wanted to batch delete all rows matching above criteria?

Comment: The problem is that you have new Date().getDate() in the hours column and so what's going to happen when the date gets to 24?  And the whole point of using that technique was to compare dates at 12 midnight and you will always be off in hours by the day of the month.

Comment: I'd recommend that you go with the last past answer.  I'm not tied to it because it's mine.  It just makes more sense not to have anything in the hours column of the Date() constructor.

Comment: I completely understand why now. Thank you for clarifying. As to my other ask about deleting rows... I can do this line by line in the for loop but that is no good. How might I do this?

Comment: The option would be to delete them from the array vs and then clear the sheet and repost the entire sheet already presorted.  However if you have formulas that could cause some problems.  Which will bring you right back to deleting them one at a time.

Comment: I do have formulas so I'll just do it line by line.